# Dashboard in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to make a macro that opens all .xlsm files in a folder:

```
C:\Users\iborrego\Desktop\zfichasmacro\Fichas excel\
```

And copy some cells (from different worksheets).

Information from each file should be assigned only to one row as I will use the first row for titles (ID Nº; Date of visit etc …)

And one row for each file in the folder.

I would really appreciate if you could help me write the macro and tell me how it works as I am not an IT.

Comment: Please understand that this is no free code writing service. Therefore you must show what you already have tried and explain where exactly your issues or errors are. Also you need to ask a question related to that code, otherwise we have nothing to answer. Reading [ask] might help to improve your question.

Comment: Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

I did not understand the second part of your question, but here is a code which opens every xlsm in your given folder:

```
Sub Xlsmopener()
Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objFile As Object
Dim i As Integer

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("C:\Users\iborrego\Desktop\zfichasmacro\Fichas excel")
i = 1
For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
 If objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFile.Path) = "xlsm" Then
 Workbooks.Open (objFile.Path)
 End If

i = i + 1
Next objFile

End Sub
```